# Maven transitive dependecy breaks build

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a following problem - I am trying to use `apache commons-lang version 2.6` in my project (which is defined in the pom.xml) but due to transitive dependency maven always add version 3.2.1 which breaks my build.
Here is relevant part of pom.xml

```
<properties>
   <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
   <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and when I try to run `mvn dependency:tree` I can see the reason is transitive dependency of

```
+- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.26.0:compile (version managed from 2.26.0)
    +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.10:compile
       +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
```

So I can see the problem but I have really no idea how to fix it. Thanks for any suggestions:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My collegue forgot to declare version in dependencyManagement in parent pom so that was it. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 4):

Look into using an exclusion tag inside the dependency that's causing the problem.  An exclusion tag tells maven that you don't want maven to bring in an indirect dependency and is used in just this situation.

For example, if one of my dependencies A brings in a version 1.0 of B but I want to use version 2.0 of B instead,  I could do this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mycorp</groupId>
    <artifactID>A</artifactID>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mycorp</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mycorp</groupId>
    <artifactID>B</artifactID>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The exclusion tag says to not bring in the indirect dependency (B 1.0) in this case.  Note that you don't have to give the version.  Once you've told maven not to automatically bring in that version of B, you follow with an explicit dependency that defines which version of B (version 2.0, in this case) you do want.

Comment: What do you mean by relevant portions (i.e. what exactly do you need)?I'll look at exclusions, thanks for tip

Answer (score 3):

This particular dependency should *not* break your build, because Commons Lang 3 uses different package naming than Lang 2. Your code should use the classes from Lang2, while HTMLUnit will use the classes from Lang3, and both JARs can co-exist.

Perhaps you should describe *how* you think this breaks your build, with relevant extracts from the build output.